# Action Controller: Exception Caught [NoMethodError in Home#index]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, actioncontroller

I am trying to set up a local development environment for a ROR app that has been passed down to me from a previous developer. I am new to ROR and Ruby.

First I run `bundle install` with no problems, then `mongod`. When i run `rails s` the server starts, but it outputs `host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection`.

When I try to go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000` an error message appears.
`NoMethodError in Home#index`

The error points to the following path:

Showing /Users/ryansnyder/Rails/myAppX/app/views/home/index.html.haml where line #12 raised:

`undefined method 'url' for nil:NilClass`

Extracted Source (around line #12):

```
9:     %h2 Asset Protection
10:     = link_to image_tag('asset-protection-guide.png'), 'http://myAppX.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/downloads/myAppX-AssetProtectionGuide.pdf', :title => 'Asset Protection Guide', :alt => 'Download our Asset Protection Guide', :target => '_blank'
11:   %section#graphs
12:     = link_to image_tag(@chart.url, :alt => @chart.alt), eval(@chart.link), :title => @chart.title
13: 
14: %section#recent-happenings
15:   %section#upcoming-events
```

I commented out that line in the .haml file, and refreshed `http://0.0.0.0:3000` and received another `undefined method 'question' for nil:NilClass` error. I assume that this is either a database or error handling issue. But I am only guessing.

EDIT:
I don't know if this helps, but when running `rake test` i receive the following output.

```
host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
/Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require': no such file to load -- turn (LoadError)
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/Rails/alerstallings-master/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/Rails/alerstallings-master/test/functional/lawyers_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/Rails/alerstallings-master/test/functional/lawyers_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/ryansnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
Errors running test:functionals!
```

EDIT 2:
mondoid.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: alerstallings_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: alerstallings_test

staging:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the Mongo-error, have you double checked the settings in your `database.yml`?

Comment: I have not, I don't know where to begin with that. Like I mentioned this was a previous developers app. I assume that he had it setup correctly originally.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon for settings in development.yml to differ between different computers/developers. The settings may have been valid for the other guy, but may be invalid for you. So double-check them.

Comment: It seems like there is a discrepancy of which db to use. The database.yml file shows that sqlite3 is used for `development`, `test`, and `production`. But also `cucumber` for `test`.

But then the mongoid.yml shows settings for development, test, staging, and production. Do these two files work together, separately, or does one override the other? I apologize, I am new to this.

Comment: Okay, my bad. :) I'm not familiar with mongoid by the `database.yml` seems not be used at all for that. Instead check the settings in `mongoid.yml` for errors :)

Comment: I am able to connect to myAppX_development db when running `mongod` and selecting the `myAppX_development` database using the `mongo` shell. So i assume that `mongoid.yml` is set up correctly. There are a few Collections in there, but it is basically empty, except for a couple default users. As far as adding error handling, how would the previous developer have gotten around that previously? Does the fact that I updated to `Rails 3.0.19` from `3.0.10` have anything to do with anything? I thought I remember reading it had something to do with nils

Comment: I don't see how successfully connecting through the mongo shell should  somehow imply that mongoid.yml is set up correctly. mongoid.yml governs how Rails connects to the db, not how the db itself is set up.

Comment: So does anyone know how I can test to see if my `mongoid.yml` is set up correctly?

Comment: You should google for `host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection`, I found some SO questions which may be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the object you're getting back is not nil. You should add some error handling and check that your database is returning the appropriate objects. A quick fix would be to conditionally run your code:

```
unless @chart.nil?
  # Your previous code here
end
```

Comment: I think the nil error is due to the fact that no db is present, so doing this would just be treating the symptoms, not the sickness itself.

Comment: I totally agree. It's just a quick fix. Most of the time you *want* to be returned nil for proper error handling.

Comment: You guys were right. It was all because my db was empty. So i found out how to do a mongodump and mongorestore. Now my app is running on my local machine. Thanks for your help!